# What are the rules about playing words which are inside already-played words?

Tags: ios, letterpress

What are the rules about playing words which are inside already-played words?  In the image below, a player couldn't play "Cabbage", because "Cabbages" which was already played.

Is it just about the "S" at the end of the word?  Could a player play "war", "spa" or "pea", after "Warbles", "Spares", and "Pears"?

But then why was "Campers" allowed after "Scampers"?

[image: Letterpress Played Words screenshot showing "Scampers" and then "Campers" played.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word matches are based on matching first letters:

```
camps
camp - invalid: all of this word is in an already played word, both match starting at the first letter
campers - acceptable: they differ at camps' "s"
scams
scam - invalid: scams is longer both match at beginning
scampers - acceptable: camper starts with "c;" scampers is longer than scam & differs from scams at the second "s"
```